# How to capture substrings that start with a hashtag?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, substring

I'm looking for php code to split word from text using regex, `preg_match()` , `preg_split()`, or any other way.

```
$textstring="one #two three #four #five";
```

I need to get `#two`,`#four`, and `#five` saved as array elements.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **We are not a code writing service.** Please show us what you have tried, and detail what the problem is. Also, learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions for more tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$text="one #two three #four #five";
$parts = array_filter(
    explode(' ', $text), // split into words
    function($word) {
        // filter out all that don't start with '#' by keeping all that do
        return strpos($word,"#")===0; 
        // returns true when the word starts with "#", false otherwise
    }  
);
print_r($parts);
```

You can see it here: https://3v4l.org/YBnu3

You may also want to read up on [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use a negated character class after the `#` symbol for highest pattern efficiency:

Pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6vei8K/2))

```
#[^ ]+  #this will match the hashtag then one or more non-space characters.
```

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99d840c16b47e55254df3a93ead882ba3cbb2fac))

```
$in='one #two three #four #five';
var_export(preg_match_all('/#[^ ]+/',$in,$out)?$out[0]:'failed');  // access [0] of result
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '#two',
  1 => '#four',
  2 => '#five',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try splitting by this: `\b #`

```
preg_split("/\\b #/", $text)
```

Comment: thx for suggestion. i tried this code but still get result  
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two three
    [2] => four
    [3] => five
) just need  #two,#four,#five. thanks.